# Merging tags [link] and [links]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tags [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link) and [links](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links) refer to the same subject and thus should be merged.

Qs tagged [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link)
Qs tagged [links](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed.

A tag synonym mapping `link` → `links` has been created.